# ¿Cómo guardar una matriz en un archivo de texto?

Tags: dev-c++

Necesito ayuda.
En la universidad me dejaron un proyecto que es el siguiente:

Crear un programa en C que Simule un cajero automático.
Funciones ( todas sin parámetros)

void consultarSaldo();
void Retirar();
void Depositar();
void imprimirMovimientos();

En la ultima  función se debe declarar un fichero File *, pero los datos deben venir de un arreglo bidimensional donde se guardaran tanto los retiros como los depósitos y se trabaja con una variable global llamada saldo. 
El problema es que en mi fichero no me aparece nada y cuando me aparece solo es el último movimiento( retiro o deposito).
se me olvido mencionar que en la primera columna del arreglo bidimensional debe imprimir 1 si se retiro o 2 si se deposito.

AYUDA!!!

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora. ¿Donde esta mi error o que estoy haciendo mal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void proceso();
void consultarSaldo();
void Depositar();
void Retirar();
void imprimirMovimientos();

float saldo;
float movimientos[10][2];

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
    proceso();
}

void proceso(){
    system( "cls" );
    int opcion;
    printf( "\t\tBANCO UNACH\n\n" );
    printf( "1. Consultar saldo\n" );
    printf( "2. Retirar\n" );
    printf( "3. Depositar\n" );
    printf( "4. Imprimir Movimientos\n" );
    printf( "5. Salir\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &opcion );
    switch( opcion ){
        case 1:
            consultarSaldo();
            break;
        case 2:
            Retirar();
            break;
        case 3:
            Depositar();
            break;
        case 4:
            imprimirMovimientos();
            break;
        case 5:
            exit( 1 );
        default:
            printf( "Opcion no valida" );
            break;
    }
}

void consultarSaldo(){
    system( "cls" );
    int opcion;
    printf( "Tu saldo actual es: $%.2f", saldo );
    printf( "\n1. Regresar al menu" );
    printf( "\n2. Salir\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &opcion );
    if( opcion == 1 )
        proceso();
    else
        exit( 1 );
}

void Retirar(){
    system( "cls" );
    float retiro;
    int opcion;
    int contador1, contador2;
    printf( "Ingrese la cantidad a retirar: " );
    scanf( "%f", &retiro );
    if( retiro > saldo )
        printf( "La cantidad excede el saldo actual\n" );
    else
        saldo -= retiro;
    for( contador1 = 0; contador1 < 10; contador1++ ){
        for( contador2 = 0; contador2 < 2; contador2++ ){
            if( movimientos[contador1][contador2] == 0 ){
                movimientos[contador1][0] = 1;
                movimientos[contador1][1]= retiro;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    printf( "\n1. Regresar al menu" );
    printf( "\n2. Salir\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &opcion );
    if( opcion == 1 )
        proceso();
    else
        exit( 1 );
}

void Depositar(){
    system( "cls" );
    float deposito;
    int opcion;
    int contador1, contador2;
    printf( "Ingrese la cantidad a depositar: " );
    scanf( "%f", &deposito );
    saldo += deposito;
    printf( "\n1. Regresar al menu" );
    printf( "\n2. Salir\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &opcion );
    if( opcion == 1 )
        proceso();
    else
        exit( 1 );
    for( contador1 = 0; contador1 < 10; contador1++ ){
        for(contador2 = 0; contador2 < 2; contador2++ ){
                if( movimientos[contador1][contador2] == 0.00 ){
                    movimientos[contador1][0] = 2;
                    movimientos[contador1][contador2] = deposito;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

void imprimirMovimientos(){
    FILE *ticket;
    int contador;
    ticket = fopen("Movimientos.txt","a+");
    if ( ticket == NULL)
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero\n");

    for( contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++){
        fprintf( ticket, "%.0f ", movimientos[contador][0] );
        fprintf( ticket, "%.2f\n", movimientos[contador][1] );
    }
    fclose(ticket);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Implementas mal los bucles para recorrer el array. Solo necesitas uno para recorrer el primer nivel del arreglo y en el segundo nivel asignas los datos cuando se cumpla la condición de ser 0. Al ser el array de tipo float yo usaría < 1 por si el cero pudiese arrastrar algún decimales.

   ```
   for( contador1 = 0; contador1 < 10; contador1++ ){
       if( movimientos[contador1][0] < 1 ){
           movimientos[contador1][0] = 1;
           movimientos[contador1][1]= retiro;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. En la funcion *Depositar()* la rutina para la asignación de los datos en el arreglo la tienes justo despúes de la rutina del menu con las opciones de *regresar* o *salir* por lo que nunca se ejecutará.
3. Como añadido, el bucle para imprimir los datos en el fichero puede mejorarse para que imprima solo los que están asignados.